# Select option selected php mysql

Tags: php

Como puedo cargar un selected de un option a traves de codigo php? ya que necesito editar varios datos de una tabla, pero necesito que se carguen los datos del registro, pero en los filtros necesito que aparezca por default el valor del resultado del query, pero ademas me aparezcan todos los del listado del combo.

muestro mi codigo.

```
$query2="select id_categoria, descripcion from categoria;";
                        $result2=$con->query($query2);
                        while ($reg2=$result2->fetch())
                        {
                            echo '<option value='.$reg2['id_categoria'].' selected="'.$reg['id_categoria'].'">'.$reg2['descripcion'].'</option>';
                            //echo '<option value='.$reg2['id_categoria'].' selected="'.$reg['id_categoria'].'">'.$reg2['descripcion'].'</option>';
                        }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres rellenar tu select option con los datos de la base de datos bastaría con hacerlo de esta manera.
Haces la consulta directamente y los resultados los cargas por medio de un `while` en los `option`.

```
<?php
$query=mysqli_query($con, "select id_categoria, descripcion from categoria");
?>
<select name="categoria">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['id_categoria']."'>'".$row['descripcion']."'</option>";
}
?>        
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

aqui esta algo de codigo solo tienes que traer dos consultas

```
1- listado de datos que van en el select  ejemplo 
tabla familia
id familia
1 papa
2 mama
3 hermano

2- selecciona el registro que vas a editar por ejemplo
tablaPersonal
id nombre idFamiliar
1  x      3

en el option es haci
<option if(in_array($familiar['id']==$personal['idFamiliar'])){echo 'selected'} value="<?php echo $familiar['id']; ?>"><?php echo $familiar['nombre'];?></option>



              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Conocimientos específicos</label>
            <select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" multiple name="conocimientos[]" data-error="Es un campo obligatorio" data-live-search="true" id="conocimiento">
              <option data-hidden="true" <?php if($cadenaConocimietos[0] == '' && count($cadenaConocimietos)<=1){ echo 'selected';}?> value="NULL"></option>
              <?php foreach ($conocimientos as $conocimiento) {
              ?>
              <option <?php if(in_array($conocimiento['idConocimiento'],$cadenaConocimietos)){ echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $conocimiento['idConocimiento']; ?>"><?php echo $conocimiento['conocimiento'];?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
```